# Enhanced Class Decompiler is installed still I am unable to decompile .class to .java source?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, decompiler, sts

Enhanced Class Decompiler is installed still I am unable to decompile .class to .java source?

[image]

I am trying to decompile java core class - Collections.class - Could some one guide me how to get past this.

[image]

I am using STS 4.8.x
[image]

Comment: The [embedded JDK that is used to run Eclipse/STS4 does not contain the sources](https://twitter.com/martinlippert/status/1313820812294713345). Make sure a Java JDK is installed in your system (if missing, you can download Java e.g. from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)) and configure it in the preferences in _Java > Installed JREs_. Do not use this decompiler hack since you also want to have the Javadoc.

Comment: The source code that comes with a Java JDK includes all the comments and Javadoc that will be missing if you use a decompiler.

Comment: @greg-449 and howlger - - tx.   I want to use the sources later, for now I want to go with the decompiler just for a short while

Comment: greg-449 and @howlger -spring classes are decompiling with out issue...how is this possible.

Comment: @howlger -spring classes are decompiling with out issue thats fine... but i am seeing javadoc too... how is this possible

Comment: @RedwinD Bytecode cannot contain Javadoc comments and therefore it is not possible that Javadoc is in a decompiled class. Probably, you look at the real source code, not at a decompiled class. Fix the root problem instead of wasting time with the decompiler hack.

Comment: @howlger, i uninstalled the decompiler, still spring classes can be decompiled to sources, how is this possible... how can sts provide such feature... my pom has no sources mentioned.

Comment: @RedwinD It's done by the Maven integration: in the preferences _Maven_ there is the option _Download Artifact Sources_ which is enabled by default.

Comment: @howlger, gr8 and tx. found one `spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar` and the preference is set to download sources.

Comment: @howlger, so sad, by-default one is able to get third party sources to debug/read but not java sources :-((

Comment: @RedwinD You just have to do what I said in the first comment. You have to do this only once and it will not take much longer than it took you to install the decompiler.

Comment: @howlger, appreciate your emphasis. Added the installed JDK to STS. And ended up with  `The JAR file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar has no source attachement`. so now going after it. [openjdk-8-jdk - missing src.zip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64340084/openjdk-8-jdk-missing-src-zip)

Comment: @RedwinD Now you have a JRE (`.../jre/...`) instead of JDK. A JRE has no sources. Go for a JDK instead of adding sources to the JRE.

Comment: @howlger - You should write an answer.

Comment: @howlger - this helped [openjdk-8-jdk - missing src.zip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64340084/openjdk-8-jdk-missing-src-zip). Bye-the-way, i will be more than happy to accept if you write down an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is that the JDK embedded in the Spring Tools 4 does not contain sources. That the Spring Tools 4 application is shipped with an embedded JDK (from [Eclipse JustJ](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/)) is currently a new feature, but the missing sources is an issue that will probably be fixed in an upcoming release ([according to this tweet by the STS4 main developer](https://twitter.com/martinlippert/status/1313820812294713345)).

As solution (and workaround for the missing sources of the embedded JDK), **make sure a JDK** (not a JRE) **is installed** in your system (if missing, you can download a JDK e.g. from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)) and **configure it** in the **preferences in *Java > Installed JREs***.

Using the decompiler hack has the disadvantage that the Javadoc will be missing.